# Rails eager_load with conditions on association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails application which has *Stations* (weather stations) and *Observations*. The app shows many weather stations on a map with the current wind speed and direction.

I have a method which is used on the `stations#index` method which selects the stations and joins the latest observation per station.

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :observations
  def self.with_observations(limit = 1)
    eager_load(:observations).where(
      observations: { id: Observation.pluck_from_each_station(limit) }
    )
  end
end
```

`Observation.pluck_from_each_station` returns an array of ids. The `observations` table contains many thousands of rows so this is necessary to keep rails from eager loading thousands of records.

This method should return all the *stations* - whether the have any *observations* or not. However this is currently not the case.

```
it "includes stations that have no observations" do
  new_station = create(:station)
  stations = Station.with_observations(2)
  expect(stations).to include new_station # fails
end
```

From my understanding a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should return all rows wether the there are any results in the joined table or not. Why is this not working as expected?

This is an example of the SQL generated:

```
SELECT "stations"."id" AS t0_r0,
       "stations"."name" AS t0_r1,
       "stations"."hw_id" AS t0_r2,
       "stations"."latitude" AS t0_r3,
       "stations"."longitude" AS t0_r4,
       "stations"."balance" AS t0_r5,
       "stations"."timezone" AS t0_r6,
       "stations"."user_id" AS t0_r7,
       "stations"."created_at" AS t0_r8,
       "stations"."updated_at" AS t0_r9,
       "stations"."slug" AS t0_r10,
       "stations"."speed_calibration" AS t0_r11,
       "stations"."firmware_version" AS t0_r12,
       "stations"."gsm_software" AS t0_r13,
       "stations"."description" AS t0_r14,
       "stations"."sampling_rate" AS t0_r15,
       "stations"."status" AS t0_r16,
       "observations"."id" AS t1_r0,
       "observations"."station_id" AS t1_r1,
       "observations"."speed" AS t1_r2,
       "observations"."direction" AS t1_r3,
       "observations"."max_wind_speed" AS t1_r4,
       "observations"."min_wind_speed" AS t1_r5,
       "observations"."temperature" AS t1_r6,
       "observations"."created_at" AS t1_r7,
       "observations"."updated_at" AS t1_r8,
       "observations"."speed_calibration" AS t1_r9
FROM   "stations"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       "observations"
       ON "observations"."station_id" = "stations"."id"
WHERE  "observations"."id" IN (450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800);
```

Comment: `"observations"."id" IN (..)` Should be inside the `ON` clause and not the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happens, because u are excluding records where `"observations"."id"` is null after the `left join`:

```
eager_load(:observations).where(
  '"observations"."id" is null or "observations"."id" in (?)', Observation.pluck_from_each_station(limit)
)
```

It is *logically* the same as `left join` on two conditions, but as rails doesn't have this feature you can work around it using the `where` clause.

Comment: It happens because conditions on the right table of a left join should be placed in the `ON` clause. When they are on the `WHERE` clause the joins transform into an inner join.

Comment: @sagi: yes, but it can also be done in the `where` clause.

Comment: The spec is passing. Will look if its possible to get AR to generate a the on clause as @sagi suggested and still load the association.

Comment: @sagi: it is either that or indigestible ar query using `joins` and tricky preloading.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thought it's easier as it is basic thing for a `LEFT JOIN` .

Comment: Tried using something like `joins("LEFT  OUTER JOIN observations ON observations.id IN (#{ ids })")` but then I have to 'handle the case where ids is empty and I'm having trouble getting it to load the association properly.